# How to estimate transaction cost using Hedera SDK

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hedera-hashgraph

Is it possible to estimate transaction cost on Hedera SDK for operations like create token, wallet, mint nft etc?

As an example I'm posting minting function:

```
async mintToken(): Promise<TransactionResponse> {
    const tx = new TokenMintTransaction()
      .setTokenId(tokenId)
      .addMetadata(Buffer.from(ipfs))
      .setMaxTransactionFee(fee)
      .freezeWith(client);

    const signTx = await tx.sign(pkey);

    return signTx.execute(client);
  }
```

Node version 18,

"@hashgraph/sdk": "2.29.0",

Comment: Maybe [this](https://hedera.com/fees) can help?

Comment: @tomerpacific i need to calculate this using offical Hedera SDK

Comment: If you want to calculate feeds denominated in USD, @tomerpacific is right, [this](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/networks/mainnet/fees) lists all of those fees, and they do not change from transaction to transaction, so there is not much point really in querying these fees from the SDK.
Note that interactions with smart contracts (via HSCS), however, have fees calculated based on computational and storage complexity (EVM gas fees), and those are indeed dynamic. This does not apply to `TokenMintTransaction` that you have used in your transaction.